# How can I animate 'a' element on a mouse click before the redirection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a navigation (class="menu-js-nav") and each item (a) is a link to a different web site. I want to animate the 'a' element on mouse click and when the animation is finished, then the browser should open the web site of the clicked 'a' element.

So, I tried to prevent default, then make the animation. Now I need to execute the default action which was prevented. I tried several ways but I was always redirected to the link without any animation. How should I write the code to say that (after a mouse click) first I want to make the animation of 'a' item and AFTER that I want to be redirected to a desired web site?

```
$('.menu-js-nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('spinner').css({
      position: 'relative'
    }).animate({
      left: 150
    }, 1000).animate({
      top: -1000
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: `animate` accepts a callback which is called whenever the animation completes - see the parameter `complete` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

As per [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) animate support a function call in complete section.

So just make link opening a function in the complete part of animate

```
$('.menu-js-nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link_to = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).addClass('spinner').css({
      position: 'relative'
    }).animate({
      left: 150
    }, 1000).animate({
      top: -1000
    }, 1000, function(){
            //open your link here
            window.location.href = link_to;
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi, what should I type into '//open your link here'? There is a different href in each 'a', for example index.html, contact.html, about.html... So, I need to open the one which was clicked on. I cannot write here only one as I don't know which one will be chosen by a user.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include what you are asking for. Please note that since i have not seen your html I assume that each link is in the href attribute

Comment: @Jayna you are welcome! Please then mark the answer as correct